# Opening new window in wicket

Tags: window, wicket

Can any one please suggest a way to open some pages in a new window in wicket.
I am trying to open a new browser window and print using javascript window.print() it content then close and open other and so on after a form is submitted . I am using wicket 1.4.22.

And when i tried it with ModelWindow the window.print() is not printing the model window content but the entire main page.

So i think popupsetting is not suitable for this purpose, and i couldn't find any other option, please help.

Comment: Are you trying to open a new modal window or a new browser window?

Comment: i am trying for a new browser window.

Comment: Why is popupsetting not suitable.  Didn't notice that line until after submitting my answer, which is about popupsettings...

Comment: popupsetting is not suitable because i need to open multiple windows one after the other and prints it content.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding, popupsetting is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any [`Link`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/Link.html#setPopupSettings%28org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.PopupSettings%29), you can specify [`PopupSettings`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/PopupSettings.html), and if you do, the page resulting from clicking that link will be opened in a new window.

There are some [examples for this](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/linkomatic/) (and other link stuff) which may be helpful.  To browse the source code click on the "Source Code" link in the upper right corner.

This is for actually doing it from a click on a link.  To do it as a result of a form submission, to trigger a javascript `window.print()`, and to cycle through multiple invocations of something like this will be more difficult, but this might be useful as a part of your solution.